# React leaflet not rendering properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, leaflet, react-bootstrap, react-leaflet

The `react-leaflet` map does not get rendered properly.

- The map is rendered outside of its parent's boundaries
- Some tiles of the map are missing

The problem occurs when using the map with standard `react` components.

My site also uses `react-bootstrap`. As I have read this may cause some potential problems to how `react-leaflet` gets rendered.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

const position = [37.335556, -122.009167];

class MapView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
                  <div
                    style={{
                        height:"100%"
                    }}>
                    <Map center={position} zoom={13}>
                        <TileLayer
                          url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        />
                        <Marker position={position}>
                          <Popup>
                            <span>A pretty CSS3 popup.<br/>Easily customizable.</span>
                          </Popup>
                        </Marker>
                      </Map>
                  </div>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = MapView;
```

[image: This gets rendered]

Answer (score 24):

first at all, install via console:

```
> npm install leaflet 
> npm install react-leaflet
```

in the index.js import a css wich is living in node_modules

```
//src/index.js
    import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
```

so, now just put a margin and height:

```
    ////src/App.js 
return (
            <MapContainer center={position} zoom={3} scrollWheelZoom={false} 
        style={{ height:"`enter code here`400px",backgroundColor:"red",marginTop:"80px", marginBottom:'90px'
            }} >
        </MapContainer>
        )
```

or

```
   return (
        <>
          <Map style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh" }} center={center} zoom={13}>
            </Map>
</> )
```

Comment: This is lightyears better than leaflet's documentation. Thanks.

Comment: I 100% agree with @TTS, totally better than the original documentation. Many thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Also add these Leaflet's CSS and JS files into your project

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

Also add height to the map. it is mandatory.

Simple [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kedar2a/LnzN2/2/)
P.S. look into external resources.

Answer (score 7):

The main problem was that the CSS was not being imported and height for the Map component was not set.

I then fixed a problem with the missing Marker image by using `react-leaflet-marker-layer`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import MarkerLayer from 'react-leaflet-marker-layer';

const position = { lng: -122.673447, lat: 45.522558 };
const markers = [
  {
    position: { lng: -122.67344700000, lat: 45.522558100000 },
    text: 'Voodoo Doughnut',
  },
  {
    position: { lng: -122.67814460000, lat: 45.5225512000000 },
    text: 'Bailey\'s Taproom',
  },
  {
    position: { lng: -122.67535700000002, lat: 45.5192743000000 },
    text: 'Barista'
  },
  {
    position: { lng: -122.65596570000001, lat: 45.5199148000001 },
    text: 'Base Camp Brewing'
  }
];

class ExampleMarkerComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const style = {
      border: 'solid 1px lightblue',
      backgroundColor: '#333333',
      borderRadius: '50%',
      marginTop: '-5px',
      marginLeft: '-5px',
      width: '10px',
      height: '10px'
    };

    return (
      <div style={Object.assign({}, this.props.style, style)}></div>
    );
  }

}

class MapView extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
                  <div
                    style={{
                        height:"700px"
                    }}>
                    <Map center={position} zoom={13}
                        style={{
                            height:"700px"
                        }}>
                        <TileLayer
                          url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        />
                        <MarkerLayer
                            markers={markers}
                            longitudeExtractor={m => m.position.lng}
                            latitudeExtractor={m => m.position.lat}
                            markerComponent={ExampleMarkerComponent} />
                      </Map>
                  </div>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = MapView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this, it for React.js or Next.js, right now it's working on react.js 18.

First i recommend to uninstall any leaflet library then install this one

```
npm i leaflet leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility leaflet-geosearch
```

You can use this code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useMemo, useCallback } from 'react'


const markerRef = useRef(null)
const eventHandlers = useMemo(
        () => ({
            dragend() {
                const marker = markerRef.current
                if (marker != null) {
                    // setPosition(marker.getLatLng())
                    console.log(marker.getLatLng())
                }
            },
        }),
        [],
    )
    useEffect(() => {
     // you will get the current position of the marker here
        console.log(markerRef.current)
    }, [markerRef.current])

//////////////////////
/// in the html

<MapContainer center={[40.8054, -74.0241]} zoom={14} scrollWheelZoom={false} style={{ height: "400px", width: "100%" }}>
    <TileLayer
    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
        <Marker
            eventHandlers={eventHandlers}
            position={[40.8054, -74.0241]}
            draggable={true}
            animate={true}
            ref={markerRef}
        >
       <Popup>
           Hey ! you found me
       </Popup>
   </Marker>
</MapContainer>
```

Copied from [here](https://dev.to/tsaxena4k/integrating-next-js-with-leaflet-js-mapbox-1351?signin=true)