# Next.js React Leaflet Map not Showing Properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have the next leaflet map:

[image]

But is not showing anything properly, only when I drag the map and only loads the parts that you can see in the upper left corner, as the second image.

I have discovered that the error only happens at the first render, If I navigate to other page without refresh (next Link component) then it appears correctly.

My code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

function Map({ coordinates }) {
   const [position, setPosition] = useState(coordinates);
   return (
      <MapContainer center={position} zoom={100} scrollWheelZoom={false} style={{ height: "500px", width: "100%" }}>
         <TileLayer attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
         <Marker position={position}>
            <Popup>
               A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </Popup>
         </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
   );
}

export default Map;
```

I have installed `react-reaflet` and `leaflet`, I also imported the CSS and specified the width and the height of the container, as others solutions in Stack Overflow indicates, but nothing works.

How I import the component in Next (because leaflet does not support Server Side Rendering):

```
/**
 * Leaflet makes direct calls to the DOM when it is loaded, therefore React Leaflet is not compatible with server-side rendering.
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64634759/9244579
 */
const Map = dynamic(() => import("../../components/Map"), {
   loading: () => <p>Map is loading</p>,
   ssr: false, // This line is important. It's what prevents server-side render
});
```

Comment: Please try it with `width: 500px`

Comment: @FalkeDesign don't seems to work :(

Comment: `zoom={100}`?  is that right?

Comment: might find some clues at [leaflet loads incomplete map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037178/leaflet-loads-incomplete-map)

Comment: Yes I tried adjusting the zoom but nothing @SethLutske

Comment: here I have the simplest version
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/73884898/10128320](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73884898/10128320)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the problem.

I discovered that if I resize the window the map shows properly, so what I had to do is to call `invalidateSize()` function every 100 miliseconds for having the size of the screen updated all the time, this will work at the first render too.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { MapContainer, Circle, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

function Map({ coordinates }) {
   const position = coordinates;
   const fillBlueOptions = { fillColor: "#0484D6" };
   const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {
      if (map) {
         setInterval(function () {
            map.invalidateSize();
         }, 100);
      }
   }, [map]);

   return (
      <MapContainer center={position} zoom={20} scrollWheelZoom={false} style={{ height: "400px", width: "100%" }} whenCreated={setMap}>
         <TileLayer attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
         <Circle center={position} pathOptions={fillBlueOptions} radius={50} />
      </MapContainer>
   );
}

export default Map;
```

Take into consider that you have to add the propert `whenCreated={setMap}` to the MapContainer component.

Answer (score 2):

Side note in 2022 about this topic: it sounds like that if your map is not rendering as intended (missing tiles and so on) you forgot to comply with every point the documentation mentioned:

> If the map is not displayed properly, it is most likely because you
> haven't followed all the prerequisites.
>
> Make sure all dependencies are installed and using supported versions
> Make sure Leaflet's CSS is loaded Make sure your map container has a
> defined height

Taken from: https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/start-setup/

In my case, missing the height of the map was rendering just some tiles.